# Using Integral to prove limit of series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I will be referencing A.3.7 and A.3.8 in this screenshot: 
[image]

First, in A.3.8, the hint follows from the definition of integral, correct (because as $\Delta x_0 \rightarrow 0$ the integral becomes the sum)? Granted, wouldn't that give us equality not $\geq$, in which case I am not correct?

Also, how would I go about showing A.3.7? Lets say the sum equals the integral as the intervals used to define the integral go to zero (if this is not true please correct me and show me why. Note that this may also answer my question about A.3.8). Integrating $\int t^{-a}dt$ gives us $\frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a}$. I don't see how I can go from there to saying that $\sum{1/i^a} < $ infinity.

EDIT: I'm going to put here a rough sketch of what I believe answers my questions (the current 2 answers below are good, but not quite what I was looking for).

For both A.3.7 and A.3.8 I believe that the integral needs to be less than the sum because the functions are decreasing functions (so you can take an integral from $n$ to $n+1$ as done in the answer below, and $\Delta x$ must be $\leq 1$ and any point, $x$ in the interval must be below $f(x)$ because the function is decreasing. That takes care of my questions regarding the hint to A.3.8. For A.3.7 I guess I could just use the fact that if the sum is less than infinity $a$ can't be less than $0$ because if it was you would have an infinite term (so the sum is infinity), and if $a=0$ you get infinity as well. The reverse direction follows from figuring out the integral (and comparing the integral to the sum).

I hope that helps someone. And my apologies for not typing this up rigorously.

Comment: The alarming thing there is that $\log{1}=0$, so the series in A.3.8 has the $i=1$ term undefined anyway...

Comment: I did realize that before posting. However, this is from a textbook, so I'm not sure what to tell you. I'm more concerned with A.3.7 and why I can say a summation is $\geq$ the equivalent integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:$f:[1,∞)\to [0,∞)$ is a decreasing function. Then $\int_{1} ^{\infty}f(x)dx<+∞$if and only if $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)<+∞$. 
for first one use change variable $u=\log x$, and for second one $y=\log\log x$
$$\int_{1} ^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}dx=\log x\vert_{1} ^{\infty}=\infty$$
$$\int_{2} ^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x(\log\log x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{\log\log x}\vert_{2} ^{\infty}<\infty$$
since $\log\log 2$ is negative we start from $n=3$ with out loss of generality.
$$\int_{2} ^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x(\log\log x)}dx=\log\log x\vert_{2} ^{\infty}=\infty$$

Comment: Your answer is in the loop, i.e. you simply rewrote the statement you have to prove.

Comment: @A1DHTH, sorry. I edit it

Comment: I tried to cancel the down vote but couldn't. I will upvote your next post.

Comment: It is ok, dear :)

Answer (score 0):

For $A.3.8$: $\dfrac{1}{n\log n} \geq \displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{x\log x} dx\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n\log n}\geq \displaystyle \int_{2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x\log x}dx=+\infty$

Comment: but why can you say that $\frac{1}{n log n} \geq \int\frac{1}{x log x} dx$? Is it just a well-known property?

Comment: i think it was better to use that theorem i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: It works because $ \int_a^b f(x) dx \leq sup(f)(b-a)$.